# Removing a digit from a number in c++

Tags: c++

I wanted to write a program that would remove the numbers I give it from my number
For example, if I give 10200 to him and 2 to him, deliver 1000
I managed to write it with Python, but I have a question and challenge whether it can be done with C ++ or not

for example:
...input:1234 3
...output:124

How can it be done with "do while"??

Comment: No doubt this can be done in C++.:)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: *whether it can be done with C ++ or not* -- C++ is used to produce game software, operating systems, business software, stock market predictors, CAD programs, disk utilities, etc. etc..  So asking whether C++ can be used to write a program to remove a digit from an integer?  That can't be your real question -- if it is, then the answer is "of course you can use C++ to do this".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow
how?

Comment: So, what's stopping you from writing the program?

Comment: @mohammadjbakhshi By using the same approach used in your program in Python.:)

Comment: Input or convert the number to a string.  **Digits** in a number are easier to manipulate when the number is a string.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I do not know C ++ well
I wanted to see if it can be done with do while or not?
And how?

Comment: The solution is a typical one liner. No idea, why we would need "do while" for it. Maybe for academical purposes? Anyway, you could use: ````std::string test{ "1234" };std::cout << std::regex_replace(test, std::regex("3"), ""); ````

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is what you looking for:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int deleteNumber(int num, int n)
{
  
    // Get the length of digits
    int d = log10(num) + 1;
  
    // Declare a variable
    // to form the reverse resultant number
    int rev_new_num = 0;
  
    // Loop with the number
    for (int i = 0; num != 0; i++) {
  
        int digit = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
  
        // skip to add if the number is what we need to remove
        if (digit == n) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            rev_new_num = (rev_new_num * 10) + digit;
        }
    }
  
    // Declare a resultant number var
    int new_num = 0;
  
    // Loop with the number
    for (int i = 0; rev_new_num != 0; i++) {
  
        new_num = (new_num * 10)
                  + (rev_new_num % 10);
        rev_new_num = rev_new_num / 10;
    }
  
    // Return the resultant number
    return new_num;
}
  
  
// Driver code
int main()
{
  
    int num = 123432111;
    
    // the digit to be deleted
    int n = 1;
  
    // Remove the specified digit from starting
    cout << deleteNumber(num, n) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

do while version of it would be:

```
// C++ implementation of above approach
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int deleteNumber(int num, int n)
{
  
    // Get the length of digits
    int d = log10(num) + 1;
  
    // Declare a variable
    // to form the reverse resultant number
    int rev_new_num = 0;
  
    // Loop with the number
    do {
        int digit = num % 10;
        // skip to add if the number is what we need to remove
        if (digit == n) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            rev_new_num = (rev_new_num * 10) + digit;
        }
        
    } while(num = num / 10);
  
    // Declare a resultant number var
    int new_num = 0;
  
    // Loop with the number
    for (int i = 0; rev_new_num != 0; i++) {
  
        new_num = (new_num * 10)
                  + (rev_new_num % 10);
        rev_new_num = rev_new_num / 10;
    }
  
    // Return the resultant number
    return new_num;
}
  
  
// Driver code
int main()
{
  
    int num = 123432111;
    
    // the digit to be deleted
    int n = 3;
  
    // Remove the specified digit from starting
    cout << deleteNumber(num, n) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: edited the answer with do while as well

Comment: frankly, this turns a rather simple task into an overcomplicated solution. How about using a `std::string` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I totally agree with you, We can also either take the inputs as strings or convert them at runtime and this will make the life whole lot easier, but the OP was specific about numbers and also the 'do while' approach.

Comment: is `"1234"` not numbers?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number okay I don't wanna have an argument in here. but I answered as per my understanding. And here is what my understanding is : Number implies numeric data type hence int, float etc. and "1234" is a string because 1 != "1" (unless you are using javascript).